# Google Workspace Migrate Gmail API Limit

Tags: api, gmail

I'm using Google's Workspace Migrate tool to move Gmail data for users from one Workspace domain to another. After about 10 minutes, Gmail message migrations stop with an error saying "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per minute per user" of service "gmail.googleapis.com' for [Google Cloud project number]."

I don't see in Google Cloud that I'm actually hitting any limits. I don't have the ability to throttle API requests as I'm using a tool provided by Google. Do "free" Google Cloud projects have different limits than "paid" projects?

I'm expecting Google's tool to work as advertised. I have a case open with their support, but I'm not getting anywhere fast when it comes to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hello  Not sure if you already got an answer to this, but I recommend checking the Quotas page on GCP to see your current usage. You can access that [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.11287677.810372760.1676381399-437187257.1673515507). Search for the "Queries per minute per user"  metric for the Gmail API and look at your "Seven-day peak usage percentage". A note, though, since your question was posted more than seven days ago, you might need to rerun a migration to see your current usage.

Regarding your question about the limit for "free projects", I can't really help there. I can tell you that on our project (which has a billing account attached), we have the limit set to 15,000.

You can always ask Google to increase your quota if you're not getting enough for your use case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).